# AWS Tag Editor - Region "Africa (Cape Town)" not available in list of regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In the Tag Editor (Resource Groups & Tag Editor) you can select the applicable regions in the "Select regions" dropdown. Most of the AWS regions are there, but I do not see `af-south-1` which is "Africa (Cape Town)". I tried my best to find information about this in the AWS documentation, but so far no luck. If anyone could elaborate on this, that would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I should note that we already have EC2s running in `af-south-1`, which is why I am a bit confused.

Comment: Could be human error - maybe the AWS tag editor team forgot about SA.

Answer (score 1):

**af-south-1** is an Opt-In AWS Region, as listed in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html#concepts-available-regions

You need to actively enable access to this region for your account.

Comment: We have instances running in *af-south-1* already though, which is why I don't understand why the region is not in the dropdown in the Tag Editor. Do I have to undertake any specific actions to make the Tag Editor work with this region?